# Fill a 4x4 grid with minimal sum of positive integers in a way that adjacent cells contain numbers of different parity

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Find a 4x4 grid containing 16 unique positive integers with minimum sum, such that adjacent numbers have different parity.

Comment: Can't you just have a checkerboard grid with 0s and 1s?

Comment: @newQOpenWid thanks forgot about that condition

Comment: Oh, and are integers non-negative, or can they be negative numbers?

Comment: thanks, minimal sum implied positive integers but I forgot about that too :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, we note that the parity of the numbers must be in this arrangement, ignoring rotations and reflections (0 for even and 1 for odd):

```
1|0|1|0
0|1|0|1
1|0|1|0
0|1|0|1
```

It is now rather easy to generalize this, to unique positive integers:

```
1 |2 |3 |4
8 |7 |6 |5
9 |10|11|12
16|15|14|13
```

which has a total sum of **136**.

Comment: Yes, sounds about right.